# Issues in deleting and modifying database

Tags: php

I’m trying to:

1. Upload a picture
2. Delete old picture
3. Modify filename of new picture in database.

Note that the value for `$foto` is in `lock.php` and it stands for picture filename.

lock.php:

```
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select user, name, email2, email, lname, sex, pic1 from miembros    where user='$user_check' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
$login_session=$row['user'];
$foto=$row['pic1'];
```

Here is my code changeprofilepic.php:

```
include('lock.php');

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$foto = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "C&oacute;digo de retorno: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
echo "<p align='center'><img src='fotoperfil/$foto' width='300'/></p>";  
echo "<b>Archivo:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "<b>Tipo de Imagen:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "<b>Tama&ntilde;o:</b> " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
if (file_exists("fotoperfil/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
  echo "<p style='color:red'><b>Error:</b> $foto ya existe! Por favor elija otro nombre de archivo.</p>";
  echo "<p align='center'><button class='bon' onclick='goBack()'>Ir atr&aacute;s</button><input type=button class='bon' onClick='location.href=\"mailto:info@example.org\"' value='Contactar al Administrador'></p>";
} else {

if(is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "fotoperfil/$foto") && $foto != 'nopic.png')      {
   // remove the old file 
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "fotoperfil/$foto");
}
// move the new file *after* the unlink
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"fotoperfil/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
// If I understand your comment: update the $foto value with new filename
$foto = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
mysql_query("UPDATE miembros SET pic1 = '$foto' WHERE user = '$login_session'");
```

The problem is the code will delete the same picture that I just uploaded. My goal is to just delete the old picture.

Comment: in your code (assumption $foto == 'cavaliers.gif'), 
if new file name is == 'cavaliers.gif' you delete the new file just after uploaded, 
if new file name is != 'cavaliers.gif' you don't set the new file into the DB,
in both cases you loose

Comment: before that i got an if exist file code, ill update the full code

Comment: $foto = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; @ line 6 of changeprofilepic.php may be the problem

Comment: i see now, why it could be happening. Ill let u know when i change variables name now.

Comment: The problem was on line 6, thx, changed $foto value to picture, as left the $foto of lock.php intact, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the old file before move the new uploaded file. You can check also if exist an old file.

```
include('lock.php');
// If I got an old file AND still exists on FS
if(is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "fotoperfil/$foto") && $foto != 'nopic.png') {
  // remove the old file 
  $elim = unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "fotoperfil/$foto");
}
// move the new file *after* the unlink
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"fotoperfil/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
// If I understand your comment: update the $foto value with new filename
$foto = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
mysql_query("UPDATE miembros SET pic1 = '$foto' WHERE user = '$login_session'");
```

Comment: read again the code. i forgot to add the if != nopic.png that was originally in my code.

Comment: well, may be better comprehension sharing a bigger snippet of code. In every case, you should avoid to delete your new photo :)

Comment: What i dont understand is: if in $foto value at the start of the code is: cavaliers.gif, and in line 3, it still works as cavaliers.gif. But why when it gets to line 4, it reads it as if the UPDATE of line 7 has already happened?

Comment: I've modified the code, did I understood correctly your comment?

Comment: i got this error with ur previously code: Warning: unlink(/home/www/------/fotoperfil/bucks.gif) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in

Comment: $foto value was already given in lock.php, i will have to add it again?

Comment: I think you have to update $foto because '$_FILES["file"]["name"]' could be different from 'cavaliers.gif'

Comment: i updated the code, and add the lock.php so u can se from where comes $foto, ill try to work out ur new code now, thx.

Comment: for some reason is not deleting the old file now.

Comment: check the whole code, now the problem is that its not deleting the old files, and no error msg appear.